# MySQL Statement to create 'End Time' of operational shift, when i only have the next persons start time

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am struggling to create an SQL statement to calculate the end time of a drivers shift from the start time of the next driver. I have multiple drivers driving the same truck, and need to know which driver is driving at which time. For this, I require a column for the start and end time of their stint driving the truck.

Example below, driver 69 starts his shift at 1:55am on fleet 6, he is then replaced by driver 26  at 13:55, so logically i know the end time of his shift is 13:55. However i cant workout the SQL statement to create this column.This table is a continuous table spanning multiple dates.

[image: Table example here]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show an attempt.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use `lead()`.  Let me assume you are using an earlier version:

```
select s.*,
       (select min(s2.start_datetime)
        from shifts s2
        where s2.start_datetime > s.start_datetime
       ) as end_datetime
from shifts s;
```

This is much simpler with `lead()`:

```
select s.*,
       lead(s.start_datetime) over (order by s2.start_datetime) as end_datetime
from shifts s;
```